# How to draw narrow rectangle between rows in datagridview c#?

Tags: datagridview

Searching didn't help me. Sorry, if duplicate.

In my application I have a datagridview with many columns. Users wish to have some more columns, but there is no more place on the screen to show additional columns! So I suggested to draw a rectangle with some information based on differrent colors. But can't find a solution to do this.
Here is picture with what I have:
[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2fxc.png)
I've tried this code:

```
        private void dgSummon_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(e.RowBounds.X, e.RowBounds.Y + e.RowBounds.Height / 2,
                                e.RowBounds.Width, e.RowBounds.Height / 2);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, rect);
    }
```

And here what I managed to do:
[what I can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2iEG.png)

but these Aqua rectangles are the part of the row and hide part of information. I need these rectangles to be *between* rows!

Please, tell me is it possible? If no, what else can I do to achieve this?

Thank you and sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to do this!
First I must set DividerHeight of the row for example to 20. Then paint on this divider.
some code:

```
    //somewhere make row and insert it in row collection of datagridview
    void makeRow()
    {
        ...
        row.DividerHeight = 20;
        ...
    }
    //paint a rectangle on this divider
    private void dataGridView_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(e.RowBounds.X, e.RowBounds.Y + 
            e.RowBounds.Height - 20, e.RowBounds.Width, e.RowBounds.Height);
        
        Brush brush;
        brush = Brushes.Green;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
    }
```